# KS Test and Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test, large differences in p values

Tags: p-value, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am relatively new to non-parametric tests. I wrote the following R code to test 2 sample tests using the KS test and the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test. Drawing 2 samples of various sizes from unit Normal and checking p values under both tests. I see a rather large variation in p-values and no convergence as sample size increases.

The R code I used is as follows:

```
    results<-data.frame(Picks=numeric(), NoTie1=numeric(), NoTie2=numeric(),  intersect=numeric(), ks.stat=numeric(), ks.pval=numeric(), wx.stat=numeric(), wx.pval=numeric(), pval.diff=numeric())
    for(i in (1:100)) {
      aa<-round(rnorm(i*10),4)
      bb<-round(rnorm(i*10),4)
      cc<-intersect(aa,bb)
      aa<-setdiff(aa,cc)
      bb<-setdiff(bb,cc)
      intersect(aa,bb)
      kst<-ks.test(aa,bb,alternative="t")
      wxt<-wilcox.test(aa,bb,alternative="t")
      results[i,]<-list(i*10,length(aa), length(bb), length(cc), kst$statistic, kst$p.value, wxt$statistic, wxt$p.value,round(abs(kst$p.value-wxt$p.value),2))
}
```

Besides this, although I draw a sample from the unit normal, p-values don't seem to converge as sample size increases.

Comment: Welcome  to Cross Validated! I've formatted the code for readability, but it still needs some commenting to explain what you're doing (not everyone speaks R) & why - in particular the rounding of the simulated observation followed by removal of ties across the two samples doesn't have any obvious motivation. It would also help to show the results & clearly explain how they differ from what you expected, as well as *why* you expected what you expected.

Comment: I rounded for readability. I did run the code without rounding and so no difference. Removed ties since for ks.test an wilcox.test expect no ties.  I expected the diff in the p-values of the tests to be larger with small sample sizes and converge to the same value with larger sample size, but didn't see that.

Comment: You introduced ties by rounding - if you want to display results to a different precision use the `digits` argument to the `print` function.

Answer (score 3):

Simulating under the null hypothesis I'd expect the following:

1. For each test, a more or less uniform distribution of p-values (see [Why are p-values uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10613/17230)). More or less because both the Mann–Whitney–Wilcoxon & Kolmogorov–Smirnov test statistics depend on ranks, so can only take a finite no. values for a given sample size. As the sample size increases the distributions should look more uniform.
2. Some positive correlation only between the p-values from each test. The test statistics are not equivalent—they partition the sample space differently—, & there's no reason to suppose their p-values will converge as sample size increases.

Your code doesn't seem well suited to investigate the relationship: make *many* simulated samples for each sample size & look at the marginal distribution of p-values for each test as well as the joint distribution of both.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I'll read the link suggested and experiment further.