# Multiple comparison problem

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, experiment-design, tukey-hsd-test

If I conduct 19 tests (e.g. 19 pairwise comparisons of treatment means in an experiment), what is the probability that I will find at least one P value < 0.05 due to chance alone? With number of pairwise comparisons given by k*(k-1)/2 where k is the number of treatment levels, how does one calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/handcomp/hclsdhsd.PDF), which says that the chance also depends on the level of significance you have set.

> The chance of committing at least one Type I error for a set of comparisons
>   can be estimated as c * .05, where c is the number of comparisons made. For our example with three conditions, we can make
>   three comparisons, this would be 3 * .05 = .15, or a 15% chance of making at least one Type I error.

Since [Type I error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) is getting p-value small even if it should not be.

> In statistical hypothesis testing, a type I error is the rejection of a true null hypothesis (also known as a "false positive" finding or conclusion)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the correlation of your 19 tests and the distribution of your $p$-values. For independent tests and uniformly distributed $p$-values (see [Why are p-values uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/why-are-p-values-uniformly-distributed-under-the-null-hypothesis) and comments) the chance for no $p$-value below 0.05 would be
$$\prod_{i=1}^{19} P(p_i<0.05)=(0.05)^{19}$$
and therefore the answer to your question regarding the complementary event is
$$1-(0.05)^{19}.$$

If the tests have a correlation of 1, the probability would only be 0.05.

If you don't know the correlation, the highest possible probability would be $19*0.05$.

> With number of pairwise comparisons given by k*(k-1)/2 where k is the number of treatment levels, how does one calculate this?

- If you have k treatment levels, you can compare the first one to **k-1** other levels.
- The next you compare to **k-2** (because you already compared it to the first one).
- The next after that to **k-3**.
- And so on ... till you compare the last but one to the last.

So what's the sum from 1 to k-1? That's the well know formula from Gauß:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i=\frac{(k-1)k}{2}.$$