# Why is the probability of a type 1 error, $\alpha$, the significance level?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

I've seen this stated [Why are p-values uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/why-are-p-values-uniformly-distributed-under-the-null-hypothesis) and [https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/inference/supporting-topics/basics/type-i-and-type-ii-error/#:~:text=The%20probability%20of%20making%20a,you%20reject%20the%20null%20hypothesis.&text=The%20probability%20of%20rejecting%20the,is%20equal%20to%201%E2%80%93%CE%B2](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/inference/supporting-topics/basics/type-i-and-type-ii-error/#:%7E:text=The%20probability%20of%20making%20a,you%20reject%20the%20null%20hypothesis.&text=The%20probability%20of%20rejecting%20the,is%20equal%20to%201%E2%80%93%CE%B2) and essentially in my other resources.

The probability of rejecting the null hypothesis is the significance level $\alpha$, which we typically take as $\alpha = 0.05$. When we reject a null hypothesis, there are two possibilities: (1) the null hypothesis was in fact correct, so we made a type 1 error (2) the null hypothesis was in fact wrong, so made a correct choice.

(1) and (2) are disjoint events, and if we denote $p_1$ and $p_2$ to correspond to their probabilities, we have

$$
p_1 + p_2 = \alpha
$$

So how is it that $\alpha$ is the probability of making a type 1 error? That would mean $p_1 = \alpha$? I guess I feel like the proper way of the phrase should be the probability of a type 1 error is at most $\alpha$?

Comment: What justifies "$p_1+p_2=\alpha$"??  In fact, what justifies associating a probability with *any* hypothesis?

Comment: @whuber Let $a$ denote the event that we reject the null hypothesis, then $Pr(a) = \alpha$. When the event $a$ occurs, there are two possibilities, $b_1$ and $b_2$, corresponding to (1) and (2) above. So $Pr(a) = Pr(a|b_1)Pr(b_1) + Pr(a|b_2)Pr(b_2)$ where above I defined $p_i = Pr(a|b_i)P(b_i)$

Comment: Your initial statement is invalid: you simply don't know the chance of rejecting the null hypothesis.  All you know is that the chance of a rejection *conditional* on the null equals $\alpha.$

Comment: @whuber Ah yes, I understand. The p values are normally distributed *under the null hypothesis*, then the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis $\alpha$. So it's a conditional probability. But does this invalidate the other stuff I said?

Comment: Yes, because everything else you write is a reaction to or consequence of that error.  (BTW, I believe you meant to write that the p-values are *uniformly* distributed under the null.)

Comment: @whuber Oops yes, I meant uniformly distributed. Ahh I get it now. Basically, my $p_2$ above, under the assumption that the null hypothesis is true, is 0.